# How to change the UI language on Clementine?

Tags: gui, language-support, clementine, audio-player

The title says it all, really. I've recently moved to Ubuntu, tried a LOT of audio players, and I'm liking the features on Clementine so far but...
It's the only program that isn't on English and it's an eyesore.
Doesn't appear to have a language selection on the configuration window and web searches have been unfruitful so far, except for this: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/clementine.1.html but I have no idea as to where to input these commands so they're recognized.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: How did you install it? What are your locale settings? I take it your Ubuntu is generally in English?

Comment: @terdon
I installed Clementine through the Ubuntu Software Center. My Ubuntu and every program I installed so far are in English, except for my keyboard input method which is on "Spanish (eliminate dead keys)" to match the hardware.
However the Clementine language localization seems to match the local use of Spanish where I live (Argentina), so I presume it's not using the keyboard input settings to set the language.
As a quick test, changed the keyboard settings to English and the UI was still on "Argentinian Spanish".

Comment: Can you please run the `locale` command and add the resulting output to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug in `clementine` or at least in the version that comes packaged with Ubuntu. I use it on my Debian and have not seen this before but I installed it today on a VM running Ubuntu and it appeared in French. I live in France but have absolutely nothing set to French on my system, much less the VM.

So, it looks like Clementine is assuming the language based on your IP or some other silly method. The good news is that there is a setting for that, at least on version 1.1.1 which is what is in the 13.10 repositories.

Just go into "Tools" => "Preferences" => "Behavior" and change the language:

[image]

Comment: Hey, many thanks. It appears I managed to miss that, I kept looking for a way to change the **UI** language in the **User Interface** section :rolleyes:
Anyways, that did the trick, one less thing to worry about now :)

Comment: @terdon: Actually, if you run the `locale` command on that VM, you'll find that a few locale categories are set to French. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with terdon that the application is buggy, but it does check the locale, it's just that it checks the wrong locale category: `LC_NUMERIC`.

Now, the solution suggested by terdon is reasonably the best. Just wanted to show a way to workaround the bug:

```
$ cat ~/bin/clementine
#!/bin/sh
export LC_NUMERIC=$( printenv LANG )
exec /usr/bin/clementine "$@"
```

I simply put the file clementine in my ~/bin folder and set the executable bit (chmod +x).

Comment: Well I'll be, you're quite right. I guess that happens when I set the time zone to France during the installation process. Very nice, +1. You don't need the script though, you could just create an alias like this: `alias clementine='LC_NUMERIC=$(printenv LANG) clementine'`. Since they're on the same line, they're run in the same subshell and the export is not needed.

Comment: @terdon: Yes, the Ubuntu installer guesses the regional format settings based on time zone location. An alias works fine if you start the app from the shell, but what if you start it from the graphical environment by clicking an icon?

Comment: And you make a very good point again, the alias will indeed not work for icons. My main point was avoiding the `export` and `exec` calls by having `LC_NUMERIC=$(printenv LANG) clementine` on a single line but I'm just being pedantic. Thanks again for the info.

Comment: @terdon: You're welcome. I'm in a talking mood tonight. :)