# How can I run Baka-MPlayer with another language?

Tags: language-support

I want to run a Baka-MPlayer (a QT application) with another language (Dutch). I tried doing `LANG=nl_NL.UTF-8 ./baka-mplayer`, but it didn't work. My current `LANG` variable is set to `en_GB.UTF-8` When I type in `LANG=nl_NL.UTF-8 locale`, it gives an error that the locale isn't installed.

Comment: More info is needed, but if you mean changing temporarily the system language so that the application detects a different language in the system if it requests it, then your answer might be here http://askubuntu.com/questions/142812/temporarily-change-language-for-terminal-messages-warnings-errors

Comment: @MyUserIsThis: Actually I think the OP may have provided sufficient info. It's a well known problem that some qt applications don't interpret the locale correctly.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't think this is a duplicate of question 142812. If at all a duplicate, I'd rather suggest http://askubuntu.com/questions/447454/how-to-change-the-ui-language-on-clementine

Answer (score 0):

Some qt applications use (incorrectly) the `LC_NUMERIC` locale category to pick the display language. Hence you may want to try:

```
LC_NUMERIC=nl_NL.UTF-8 ./application
```

Or, if that doesn't work either, try:

```
LC_ALL=nl_NL.UTF-8 ./application
```

*Edit:*

When seeing the additional info after you edited the question, it looks like you haven't installed the Dutch language. You'd better do so using [Language Support](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/prefs-language-install.html).