# QT 5 UI language and local settings

Tags: kubuntu, language-support, qt

I'm on Kubuntu 19.10
I have set
Regional Settings > Language > British English (Configure Plasma translation)

but as I'm living in another country I must set
Regional Settings > Formats > Other Country - other_LANGUAGE

Everything is fine with KDE and GTK applications (i.e. English UI and local calendar) but QT applications show the other_LANGUAGE in their menus and toolbars.

Is there a way I can fix it?
I've been "duckducking" for hours but no luck.

TIA

Comment: Can you provide an example of a Qt app which does not use the expected language?

Comment: The QT apps are VYM, MusicBrainz Picard, Clementine, VirtualBox, etc.

Comment: The QT apps are VYM, MusicBrainz Picard, Clementine, VirtualBox, etc.
Well anyway I solved the problem: 1. Changed Regional settings to English 2. Deleted any other_LANGUAGE settings 3. Logged out 4. Logged back in 5. Opened some QT apps 6. Changed Regional Settings back to Other Country
Not the best of science but it worked...

Comment: Your mentioning of Clementine [rings a bell](https://askubuntu.com/a/447468). Makes me wonder if Qt apps systematically use the wrong locale category to determine the display language.